# Avoid pops and clicks whilst recording HTML Audio

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am building an app that allows the user to record a message with the microphone and am using a node package called `mic-recorder-to-mp3`. The constructor takes a `bit-rate` setting which is currently `128` (which should be more than sufficient for voice recording).

We've started collecting recordings with this app and some are fine, but others are really awful with loud clicks and pops.

I understand that the `sample-rate` cannot be set and is based on the hardware you're using, but is there something else I am missing? Is that bit rate too high? Do I need to set more memory to the `AudioBuffer`? Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered to my delight that you can now set constraints when you call `getUsermedia` which could improve the audio recording quality. They are in the web audio specs as `MediaTrackConstraints`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints

and usage:

```
export const audioTrackConstraints = {
  echoCancellation: {exact: false},
  autoGainControl: {exact: false},
  noiseSuppression: {exact: false},
  sampleRate: 16000,
  }
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: audioTrackConstraints})
.then(() => {
  console.log('Permission Granted');
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error.message);
})
```